# Ionic 7 and MSAL Authentication not running in android studio emulator

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, msal-angular

I have tried ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code ) in ionic 7+capacitor and it works without any hassle when i do ionic serve.

However, when I run the same in android emulator it gives
clientConfigurationError: untrusted authority error.

Appreciate someone's support here as its kind of blocker

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors